# geometries for ESRI UNION REST call

Tags: vb.net, esri

The [UNION](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/SDK/REST/index.html?union.html) JSON Structure example shows two geoms, one with X and the other with Y points. Is that for real?

The doc says the geoms are like those from other REST calls.

What I am trying to do is merge two (or more) polygons (adjacent parcels) using the GeometryServer UNION. I think I am passing the two geoms in correctly but just one of the polygons is returned.

My overarching goal is to draw a 1000' buffer around multiple parcels. I can draw a buffer around a single parcel but I need to buffer both (or more) together. Perhaps I need to UNION the buffers?

Am I using the wrong service?

I am not using any Java libraries but making HTTPRequest REST calls from VB.Net.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did a UNION on the first two parcels then used a For..Loop to UNION the result with each remaining parcel.

Here is the portion of the code that performs the UNION:

```
    Dim sGeom As String = ""
    Dim URL As String = "http://serverName/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/union"
    Dim sData As String = "?sr=4251&geometries={|geometryType|:|esriGeometryPolygon|,|geometries|:[Geom1,Geom2]}&f=json".Replace("|", """")
    sData = sData.Replace("Geom1", Geom1).Replace("Geom2", Geom2)
    sData = sData.Replace("sr=4251", "sr=" & sr)
    sData = sData.Replace("""", "%22").Replace("[", "%5B").Replace("]", "%5D").Replace("{", "%7B").Replace("}", "%7D").Replace(":", "%3A").Replace(",", "%2C")

    sGeom = ""
    sGeom = PostRequest(URL & sData)
```